# Flutter: Can I put Math equations inside a Text Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, tex

I'm trying to make a math quiz game and I need to have the non-math text in a custom font while the math equations get displayed normally.

*Note: the math equations that i'm trying to display are Extremely Simple*

I'm using [flutter_math_fork](https://github.com/simpleclub-extended/flutter_math_fork) which is a fork of [flutter_math](https://github.com/znjameswu/flutter_math), if there is any better alternatives that can do what i want please till me.

So is there a way to do something like that, for example:

```
Text("${Math.tex("2^{5}")} This is a Normal Text", style: TextStyle(fontFamily:"Custom Font")
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [`Flutter Tex`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_tex)

It is a Flutter Package to render Mathematics / Maths, Physics and Chemistry, Statistics Equations and expressions based on LaTeX, TeX, and MathML with **HTML and JavaScript support**.

Here's an example with both `Tex` & `Text` together

For following code visit [here](https://github.com/shah-xad/flutter_tex/blob/master/example/lib/tex_view_document_example.dart) -

[image: Tex]

Comment: This is Amazing!. Thank you so much.

Comment: is there any way to disable text selection on this? for flutter web i am using the same.

Answer (score 0):

I found a Great Package that uses [CaTeX](https://pub.dev/packages/catex) its called [katex_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/katex_flutter) it does exactly what i want, you just need to surround the math equations with the dollar sign ($) inside a Text Widget and it well automatically separate the normal text from the math equations and render them in CaTeX.
this is a simple example:

```
DefaultTextStyle(
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  style: TextStyle(
           fontSize: 20
           ),
 child: KaTeX(
 laTeXCode: Text(
        r"This is a question $x=3^2+3^2$",
   style: TextStyle(
   color: Colors.white,
   fontFamily: "CustomFont-Bold"
            )
         ),
      ),
    )
```

output:

[image: output]